# Change integer to character in R?

Tags: r

I know this is a really stupid problem, but it's driving me nuts.

I'm trying to combine two columns in a dataframe.

One column is year, with numbers such as 2006, 2007, etc.

The other column is month, with numbers from 1-12.

I want to create a column called date that looks like this:
2012 and 12 becomes 201212
2012 and 4 becomes 201204

This should be really simple, but I can't seem to get the 0 between the 2012 and 4!!!!!!

The dataframe is called x. I have tried a number of variations of this:

```
attach(x)
x$mymonth <- as.character(mymonth)
x[!(mymonth=="10"|mymonth=="11"|mymonth=="12"),]$mymonth <- paste0("0",x[!(mymonth=="10"|mymonth=="11"|mymonth=="12"),]$mymonth)
x$mymonth <- as.character(mymonth)
x$date <- paste0(as.character(year),as.character(mymonth),"")
detach(x)
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sprintf` and specify the appropriate `fmt`.

```
df1$date <- sprintf("%04d%02d", df1$year, df1$month)
df1$date
#[1] "201501" "201502" "201503" "201504" "201505" "201506" "201507" "201508"
#[9] "201509" "201510" "201511" "201512"
```

---

Or another option would be `str_pad` from `library(stringr)` and then `paste` the columns

```
library(stringr)
paste0(df1$year, str_pad(df1$month, width=2, pad=0))
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to use `attach`.  Instead we can use `with`, `within` etc.

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(year=2015, month=1:12)
```